# How can I delete my own answer?

Tags: support, answers, deletion, deleted-answers

This question is about how and when can I delete my own answer? I mean remove the answer, not editing it and replace the text by some remark such as "the answer was deleted".

Edit: *The "delete" link displays "**vote to remove this post**"*. I thought one would only vote to delete (remove) the answer.

Comment: Have you tried actually clicking on the "delete" link? :-) (It's not a "vote"; it gets deleted. And you can undelete it later too.)

Comment: No, I have not tried. Thanks for the clarification: "It's not a "vote"; it gets deleted. And you can undelete it later too."
Anyhow perhaps the "vote to remove this post" text would better be changed to something closer to what actually it does, in my opinion.

Comment: As for your edit, this is a known bug, and was declined for being too difficult. See [meta.so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-i-have-to-vote-to-delete-my-own-answer).

Comment: I have just deleted one of my questions. Later I undeteted it. Everything worked as expected. @Kaestur Hakarl: Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There should be a "delete" link in the lower left between "edit" and "flag."  Note that deleted answers are still visible to people with 2000+ rep (until the beta ends, then it's 10000+ rep).

Comment: Actually I have seen the "delete" link but since it says "vote to remove this post" I thought something similar to "vote to close" would happen, i.e. one would only vote to delete (remove) the answer.
Perhaps I should have explained it in the question.

Comment: Now added to the question "The "delete" link displays "vote to remove this post". I thought one would only vote to delete (remove) the answer."

Comment: You will lose all reputations awarded for that answer when you delete it. If you undelete it, you will get back the lost reputations.

Answer (score 3):

Below any answer of yours, at the bottom left, you can see links for "link edit delete flag". Click on the third one, "delete".

Note that you cannot delete an answer if you are an "unregistered user", or if your answer is the accepted answer. Also, your answer will still be visible (and shown as deleted) to those with sufficiently high reputation (10000+ on Stack Overflow, probably lower here).

Comment: Oops, didn't notice another answer had been posted while typing this.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior depends on the number of answers and votes the post has.

See:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/adventures-in-delclusionism/

Comment: That applies only to questions, while Américo asked about answers.